# QGIS 3.10 not loading layers from PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am trying to load PostGIS layers in QGIS 3.10 but I don't load them, but in version 2.x I do load them normally. What will be happening, I attached an image of the error
[image: Screenshot of QGIS under Linux showing error]

```
No se pudieron obtener capas
Translated (es-ES to en-US): Could not obtain layers
```

Comment: Please always post errors to the body of the question (with an English translation if necessary). This makes the error legible on all devices and searchable as well.

Comment: the error says could not get layers

Comment: have you check using an admin user? like postgres

Comment: with the postgres user if it is possible to access the tables

Comment: Then, almost certainly you have a permission problem.

Comment: the user with whom I access owns the tables and schemas